# Generate letter grades with python

Tags: python, list

The task I have to is to generate a list of "letter grades" - examples: [A+ A A- B+ B B- …]

I have come up the following code which correctly produces such a list

```
number_of_grade_letters = 5
grade_letters=list(map(chr, range(65, 65 + number_of_grade_letters)))
grade_suffix=['+','','-']
grades = []
for l in grade_letters:
    for s in grade_suffix:
        grades = grades + [l+s]
```

My question, is there more Pythonic way to do this, particularly minimize the looping to gain efficiency as well as maintain readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, the issue is combining the grade with the suffix. You should change `grades = grades + [l + s]` to `grades.append(l + s)` to avoid re-creating a new list each time you add the new grade.

Here is the list comp equivalent of that:

```
result = [
    chr(ord('A') + i) + s  
    for i in range(number_of_grade_letters) 
    for s in ['+', '', '-']
]
```

```
print (result)

['A+',
 'A',
 'A-',
 'B+',
 'B',
 'B-',
 'C+',
 'C',
 'C-',
 'D+',
 'D',
 'D-',
 'E+',
 'E',
 'E-']
```

---

If you want to use `itertools` from the python library, here's how:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ASCII
from itertools import product

[*map(''.join, product(ASCII[:number_of_grade_letters], ['+', '', '-']))]

['A+',
 'A',
 'A-',
 'B+',
 'B',
 'B-',
 'C+',
 'C',
 'C-',
 'D+',
 'D',
 'D-',
 'E+',
 'E',
 'E-']
```

Which IMO is a little cleaner but less readable than the nested loop.

Comment: @LittleSnake Added a decent itertools alternative, although I didn't think it was initially relevant seeing as this reads like a homework assignment to me (not that there's anything inherently wrong with that, but we find a lot of people abuse the privilege to ask homework questions here).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about itertools! It's not homework btw, I'm just learning python as part of a new role

Answer (score 6):

I prefer `itertools` to generate all combinations of lists of things, using `product`:

```
import itertools
grades = 'ABCDE'
modifiers = ['+','','-']
>>> print([a+b for a,b in itertools.product(grades,modifiers)])
['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'E+', 'E', 'E-']
```

I hope this answer is rated at least an E+!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `format`, `split` and `extend` functionality,

```
grade = 5

grades = []

for i in range(grade):
    val = chr(65+i)
    grades.extend('{}+ {} {}-'.format(val, val, val).split())

print(grades, sep=' ')
```

output

```
['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'E+', 'E', 'E-']
```